# Persistent Reader() object

Tags: string, go, closures

In Go, I am trying to create a function that reads and processes the next line of input:

```
// Read a string of hex from stdin and parse to an array of bytes
func ReadHex() []byte {
    r := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    t, _ := r.ReadString('\n')
    data, _ := hex.DecodeString(strings.TrimSpace(t))
    return data
}
```

Unfortunately, this only works the first time it is called. It captures the first line but is unable to capture subsequent lines piped via standard input.

I suspect, if the same persistent bufio.Reader() object was used on each subsequent call, it would work but I haven't been able to achieve this without passing it manually on each function call.

Comment: How can a closure help here? It might be easier if you have a struct containing the reader, with ReadHex as a method.

Comment: I'll try that - thank you

Comment: @BurakSerdar The accepted answer shows how a closure can be used - I just couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/n3JtZ6tUZUE):

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func ReadFunc() func() []byte {
    r := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    return func() []byte {
        t, err := r.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        data, err := hex.DecodeString(strings.TrimSpace(t))
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        return data
    }
}

func main() {
    r, w, err := os.Pipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    os.Stdin = r
    w.Write([]byte(`ffff
    cafebabe
    ff
    `))
    w.Close()

    ReadHex := ReadFunc()

    fmt.Println(ReadHex())
    fmt.Println(ReadHex())
    fmt.Println(ReadHex())
}
```

Output:

```
[255 255]
[202 254 186 190]
[255]
```

---

2. Using a `struct`, try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/SqFw-F3ZGJX):

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

// InputReader struct
type InputReader struct {
    bufio.Reader
}

// New creates an InputReader
func New(rd io.Reader) *InputReader {
    return &InputReader{Reader: *bufio.NewReader(rd)}
}

// ReadHex returns a string of hex from stdin and parse to an array of bytes
func (r *InputReader) ReadHex() []byte {
    t, err := r.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    data, err := hex.DecodeString(strings.TrimSpace(t))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return data
}

func main() {
    r, w, err := os.Pipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    os.Stdin = r
    w.Write([]byte(`ffff
    cafebabe
    ff
    `))
    w.Close()

    rdr := New(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Println(rdr.ReadHex())
    fmt.Println(rdr.ReadHex())
    fmt.Println(rdr.ReadHex())
}
```